# Derived column headings in PIVOT expression

Tags: t-sql, pivot, multiple-columns, common-table-expression, calculated-columns

```
WITH ActiveAccountCodes AS
(
SELECT BWfkYear, BWYearID, BWFund, BWMajorObject, BWObject, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr         FROM @TmpProposedAccountCodes
UNION
SELECT BWfkYear, BWYearID, BWFund, BWMajorObject, BWObject, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr  FROM @TmpCurrentAccountCodes
UNION
SELECT BWfkYear, BWYearID, BWFund, BWMajorObject, BWObject, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr  FROM @TmpBudget1AccountCodes
UNION
SELECT BWfkYear, BWYearID, BWFund, BWMajorObject, BWObject, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr     FROM @TmpBudget2AccountCodes
UNION
SELECT BWfkYear, BWYearID, BWFund, BWMajorObject, BWObject, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr     FROM @TmpBudget3AccountCodes
)
SELECT BWObject, BWObjectDescr, Proposed, Current, Actual1, Actual2, Actual3, BWDescr
FROM ActiveAccountCodes
PIVOT(SUM(BWAmount) FOR BWYearID IN ([SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpProposedAccountCodes AS [Proposed]],     [SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpCurrentAccountCodes AS [Current]],
[SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpBudget1AccountCodes AS Actual1],
[SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpBudget2AccountCodes AS Actual2],
[SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpBudget3AccountCodes AS Actual3] )) AS PVT
```

As seen above, I am attempting to use a CTE to execute a PIVOT expression.  I am getting redlined in SSMS when I attempt to select two of the columns (Proposed and Current) that I calculated and named in the PIVOT expression.

Specifically, these lines are giving me the problem:

```
SELECT BWObject, BWObjectDescr, Proposed, Current, Actual1, Actual2, Actual3, BWDescr
FROM ActiveAccountCodes
PIVOT(SUM(BWAmount) FOR BWYearID IN ([SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpProposedAccountCodes AS     [Proposed]], [SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpCurrentAccountCodes AS [Current]],
[SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpBudget1AccountCodes AS Actual1],
[SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpBudget2AccountCodes AS Actual2],
[SELECT BWYearID FROM @TmpBudget3AccountCodes AS Actual3] )) AS PVT
```

I am not getting an error when I define the column names in the PIVOT portion of the query, but when I attempt to use them above I am getting an error.  I'm not sure of the reason for this.  Thanks for any help.  I did do some research on this before posting the question.

Comment: Would have been nice if you added some sample data since you are using table variables for your data

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need to use CTE for what you are doing unless you wanted to try it out.

I believe below example without CTE is what you are looking for. Please comment if you are looking for example of CTE.

```
    declare @TmpProposedAccountCodes table (BWfkYear int, BWYearID int, BWFund int, BWObjectDescr varchar(10), BWAmount money, BWDescr  varchar(10))
declare @TmpCurrentAccountCodes table (BWfkYear int, BWYearID int, BWFund int, BWObjectDescr varchar(10), BWAmount money, BWDescr varchar(10))
declare @TmpBudget1AccountCodes table (BWfkYear int, BWYearID int, BWFund int, BWObjectDescr varchar(10), BWAmount money, BWDescr varchar(10))
declare @TmpBudget2AccountCodes table (BWfkYear int, BWYearID int, BWFund int, BWObjectDescr varchar(10), BWAmount money, BWDescr varchar(10))
declare @TmpBudget3AccountCodes table (BWfkYear int, BWYearID int, BWFund int, BWObjectDescr varchar(10), BWAmount money, BWDescr varchar(10))

insert into @TmpProposedAccountCodes
select 0,0,0,'011', 0.1, '0.1'

insert into @TmpBudget1AccountCodes
select 2,2,2,'211', 2.1, '2.1'

insert into @TmpBudget2AccountCodes
select 3,3,3,'311', 3.1, '3.1'

insert into @TmpBudget3AccountCodes
select 4,4,4,'411', 4.1, '4.1'

insert into @TmpCurrentAccountCodes
select 1,1,1,'111', 1.1, '1.1'


select *
from (
    SELECT BWfkYear, 'Proposed' BWYearID, BWFund, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr         FROM @TmpProposedAccountCodes
    UNION
    SELECT BWfkYear, 'Current' BWYearID, BWFund, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr  FROM @TmpCurrentAccountCodes
    UNION
    SELECT BWfkYear, 'Actual1' BWYearID, BWFund, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr  FROM @TmpBudget1AccountCodes
    UNION
    SELECT BWfkYear, 'Actual2' BWYearID, BWFund, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr     FROM @TmpBudget2AccountCodes
    UNION
    SELECT BWfkYear, 'Actual3' BWYearID, BWFund, BWObjectDescr, BWAmount, BWDescr     FROM @TmpBudget3AccountCodes
) x
PIVOT(SUM(BWAmount) FOR BWYearID IN (
[Proposed],
[Current],
[Actual1],
[Actual2],
[Actual3] )) AS PVT
```